# Syntax error when running code pasted from a Python shell

Tags: python, python-idle

I want to make engineering calculator.
When I entering the code, there is no error. And when I entering the code, window appears.
However, if you load and run the saved Python file, an error will occur.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VniTt.png)

Comment: Did you just copy and paste this from the shell.... >>> just indicates an interactive shell as a chevron prompt.

Comment: No... Just open and run...

Comment: You should also mention what you're trying to do with your code.

Comment: Sorry. I modified it.

Comment: You cannot save the output of a shell and run it. You will need to remove the first two lines, and remove all the occurrences of `>>> `.

Comment: Oh!!! Thank you!!! I solve this problum.

Comment: The SyntaxError happens no matter how one runs unedited shell interaction; it is not specific to IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just copy and paste this from the shell.... >>> just indicates an interactive shell as a chevron prompt.

Remove all of the `>>>` from your code and the redundant lines.

Comment: Yeah from the comment I added... There's no answer yet so I just pasted it here to mark the question as answered.